# Conditional sink in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a mapping data flow that is checking for invalid data, with conditional split, in my file. (example row in column one < than in column two.)

I the case I don't have any invalid data I would like to copy the file in new folder.
if I have at least one error in my file I want to copy the file in an error folder.

The problem is that the validation is on the row level and I can't use a lookup.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Accept the answer that is helpful in implementing the requirement as it is beneficial for the community members

Answer (score 0):

You could have two copy activities that would execute depending on the result of your dataflow activity, [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYf5U.png) and [more info here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6128/build-azure-data-factory-pipeline-dependencies/)

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach I can think of is by using the additional file for invalid data and later the size can be evaluated to check if there any invalid records are not and assign the folder name accordingly. The invalid data can be retrieved by using filter activity in dataflow. Below GIF shows the details of the approach used.

[image]